# Removing Versions from CocoaPods Specs Repo

Tags: cocoapods, podspec

I've just published a Beta version of a Pod in the Specs Repo, using *pod trunk push*. I would like to know if is there any way of removing this version Spec from the Spec Repo. I didn't find any way of doing this via the **pod** command.

Comment: Useful question, thank you.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

CocoaPods now provides [a CLI](https://guides.cocoapods.org/terminal/commands.html#pod_trunk_delete) for deleting pods, it can be done with:

```
pod trunk delete PODNAME VERSION
```

Original answer:

Removing specs is highly discouraged. If you push a spec intending to remove it later you shouldn't push it in the first place. This is because if any users are using your spec as soon as you remove it their project will break. If this was an accident you can submit a pull request to the [specs repo](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs) removing your version. Also worth noting after removing this version you can never again push a spec with the same version number.

Comment: Actually it's a beta release and it's incorrectly versioned, so it's important to remove it. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I wanted to delete some sensitive information in podspec file in CocoaPods/spec repo , please help in achieving it.

Answer (score 18):

You can now delete specific versions of a Pod to correct an accidental push.

```
pod trunk delete PODNAME VERSION
```

You can also deprecate an entire Pod and all versions

```
pod trunk deprecate PODNAME
```

Reference: https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-trunk/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#100beta1-2015-12-30

Note that you need to be using pod version `1.0.0.beta.2` or greater. Run `pod --version` to check.  To install the beta, run `sudo gem install pod -v 1.0.0.beta.3` (get the latest version from the [ChangeLog](https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-trunk/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md))

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me:

1. On GitHub, navigate to the main page of the repository.
2. Under your repository name, click Releases.
3. On the Releases page, to the right of the release you want to delete, click Edit.
4. Delete

*[source](https://help.github.com/articles/editing-and-deleting-releases/)*